# C# connect to mysql server

Tags: c#

I need your help on this one.

I got the error message which is stated:

> "network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)".

I was trying to connect other local computer local host using ip.
My code:

```
    public DbStudent()
    {
        UGIcon = new SqlConnection();
        UGIcon.ConnectionString = "server= IPAddress;user="id";password="pass";database=MyDB";
    }
    public SqlConnection Open()
    {
        UGIcon.Open();
        return UGIcon;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        UGIcon.Close();
    }
```

Could somebody help me out please?

Comment: Your title has MySql and your error is about SQL Server, are you trying to connect to MySQL database using `SqlConnection` ?

Comment: Yes,is it possible?  or can you give me the other way to connect mysql?

Comment: I don't understand how your code may compile : your connection string contains unescaped quotes...

Comment: Your code is even can't compiled...The connection string should be `"server= IPAddress;user=id;password=pass;database=MyDB"`

Comment: i'm sorry if i cause the confusion. although i'm just the beginner on it, actually i still quite don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the installation from [MySql](http://www.mysql.de/downloads/connector/net/)

There you'll get a driver for the mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

The `SqlConnection` is used to access SQL Server, for another database use `OleDbConnection`.
So, if you want connect to `MySQL` use [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) instead.

```
    public DbStudent()
    {
        UGIcon = new OleDbConnection();
        UGIcon.ConnectionString = "Server=IPAddress;Database=MyDB;Uid=id;Pwd=pass;";
    }
```

You can see [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for MySQL Connection String